# Inheritance of the init function in php

Tags: php, zend-framework, init, object-initialization

So I have been thinking about this for a while and wondering if my init function is even working at all. This stems from the idea of [object initialization](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.initialization) in Zend Framework.

Lets Assume I have a base class like such:

```
class Base{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->init();
    }

    public function init(){}
}
```

Now lets assume I have a class from this that needs to accept a options param in the constructor. Why you wouldn't use the init function in the parent class I have no idea, but this example is based off of real code that I can't share.

```
class ExtendsBase extends Base{

    private $_options;

    public function __construct($options){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_options = $options;
    }

    // Why even instantiate this if never using it?
    public function init(){
     parent::init();
    } 
}
```

So from there we need to extend from this and actually populate init with some things.

```
class EchoHello extends ExtendsBase{

    public function init(){
        parent::init();
        echo "hello"; exit;
    }
}
```

And then we should be able to do this:

```
$someVar = new EchoHello(array());
// Instantiate should echo hello and exit.
```

The issue is that `echo "hello"; exit;` is never executed. Is there something wrong with the inheritance chain?

Comment: What you said should work but there are some syntax errors.
`class EchoHello extends ExtendBase`, there's no `ExtendBase` class, it's `ExtendsBase` and in `private _options;` you are missing something: `private $_options;`

Comment: Apologizes for this, I wrote this up right here. Sorry for the syntax errors. I was confused if this type of inheritance was working or not.

Comment: I didn't try it but I'm sure it works as you intended (without the errors of course), maybe your problem with the original code is somewhere else

Comment: I Have updated the code to remove the errors if any one can try it ... The original code is very similar set up. and when I try to echo something in it's init it doesn't work.

Comment: https://eval.in/53414

Answer (score 0):

Appranetly this piece of code executes as it should. as provided by [This eval script run.](https://eval.in/53414)